# Why JSON specification still isn't fixed to force key-value pairs in objects to be considered ordered?

Tags: json, serialization, dataformat, language-specifications

Reasons to do so seem to be very strong:

1. The requirement to keep JSON object fields order in many cases is very common. Just search the internet.
2. Even current JS engines now guarantee the order, probably after realization it is useful enough.
3. Such change in the specification will be at least forward compatible.
4. Transferred key-value pairs are ordered anyway in the serialized format so why not use it? While the order could be represented for free we are forced to ignore it and apply ugly workarounds with the current JSON spec.

Do you know any viable alternatives of JSON without such issues or any ways how to make this JSON quirk fixed?

Comment: What's the question? Nothing prevents you from serializing your JSON in a guaranteed order. No idea what ugly workarounds you need to apply.

Comment: The specification does prevent. Non-standard json read later by standard parser will drop ordering.

Comment: Depends on what parser you use. Most of the ones that I come in contact with either maintain order or have an option to maintain order. The most common example being recent JS engines.

Comment: You also state that "the order could be represented for free". While this is true for the serialized JSON format, it is not the case for the underlying data structures used in most languages. For Java, for example, I would start having to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a regular `HashMap`, which would significantly impact performance. For machine-to-machine communication, the order is just not relevant in most cases.  There are some exceptions like streaming parsers where it could be relevant, but this is not a very common use case.